# textfields should change characters in range only first one is executing

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

Can any one help me with this below code using textfields should change characters in range only first one is executing??

```
#define ACCEPTABLE_CHARACTERS1 @" 1234567890"

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField
    shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range
                replacementString:(NSString *)string 
{
    // first one................//
    if (textField == self.phoneField)
    {
        NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:ACCEPTABLE_CHARACTERS1] invertedSet];

        NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

        return [string isEqualToString:filtered];
    }

    // second one ........                  
    if (textField == self.phoneField) {

        if (((range.location == 3)) ||( range.location == 7)) {

            _phoneField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@", textField.text, string];

             return NO;
        }
        else  if (range.length == 1 &&
                  (range.location == 4 || range.location == 8))  {
             range.location--;
             range.length = 2;
             textField.text = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];

             return NO;
        }

        if (range.length+range.location > textField.text.length) {
             return NO;
        }

        NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;

        return  newLength <=10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you need here ?

Comment: i wont both expressions should execute sir

Comment: First if closure will every time return value either NO or YES. So your control will not go to second if closure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See You are using two if statements. but at the end of the first if statement You are using **return**, so the control will come out of that loop. Even both the condition are right.
Simple explanation.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (1) {
        NSLog(@"true");
        return;
    }
    if (true) {
        NSLog(@"true1");
        return;
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib
}
```

It will Print only **true** and not the *true1* because the control will come out.

Answer (score 1):

Because your are returning the function value in first `if` block it will not execute the second `if` block, the `return` statement immediately ends execution of the current function, and **returns** its argument as the value of the function call.

To do a number formatted for your textField do like this

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

    NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"1234567890"] invertedSet];

    NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

    if (![string isEqualToString:filtered]) {
        return NO;
    }
    if (((range.location == 3)) ||( range.location == 7))
    {

        textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@", textField.text, string];
        return NO;
    }
    else  if (range.length == 1 &&
              (range.location == 4 || range.location == 8))  {
        range.location--;
        range.length = 2;
        textField.text = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];

        return NO;
    }

    if (range.length+range.location > textField.text.length) {
        return NO;
    }
    NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
    return  newLength <=12;
}
```

Comment: yes sir i have found that but i am un able to change that one i removed that return expression still the code doesn't  executes..can you modify it...and thank you

Comment: @vamsi Replace your `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` with my one this will work in way you want.